# Can we limit results of a sub collection in firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to build a chat app with firestore, I am confused on setting up messages in a room as sub collection or as a root collection. If I use sub collection how do we limit the records returned from that sub collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a subcollection `messages` under each document in a colllection `rooms` then you can get the messages for a room `room1` by first creating a reference the collection:

```
var ref = firebase.firestore().collection('/rooms/room1/messages');
```

And then getting the documents:

```
ref.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.forEach(function(document) {
    ...
  });
});
```

If you only want to get the 10 most recent messages by a field called `timestamp`, you do:

```
ref.orderBy("timestamp", "desc").limit(10).get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
  ...
```